# Javascript framework for transform objects in browser(drag, scale, rotate and skew)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a JavaScript framework that could make an environment like [polyvore.com](http://www.polyvore.com/). There is a jQuery plug-in called [jQuery transformable](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/jquerytransformablejs) that doing same thing but that is not compatible with IE7. Polyvore works in IE7. I guess even in IE6!

If you know a good framework in this area that is IE compatible please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Check jquery UI http://jqueryui.com/ if you haven't yet.

Comment: jQuery UI don't have "rotate" and "skew". Actually I developed the rotatable but I want something ready to use

Answer (score -1):

You could try [cssSandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/), implements transforms and animations, even on IE.